# List behaviour in Python

Tags: python, list

I understand that the following code:

```
list_1 = [1]
list_2 = list_1
list_1[0] = 2
print(list_2)
```

gives 2 as output.

However, what I do not understand is that

```
list_1 = [1]
list_2 = list_1
list_1 = 2
print(list_2)
```

Does not give 2 as an output, but 1 instead?

Comment: `list_1[0] = 2` is altering the contents of your list. `list_1 = 2` is altering the variable `list_1`.

Comment: In first case, you modify a list, in the second case, you rebind a variable. Those two are very different things.

Comment: The usual excellent recommendation: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Python variable is a symbolic name that is a reference or pointer to an object. Multiple variables can point to the same object. Changing a variable assignment for one variable does not change the value of another variable.

Must understand what the code `list_2 = list_1` vs `list_1[0] = 2` means. The first is a variable assignment (or binding) and the second is object manipulation.
**This is an important distinction**.

1. variable assignment
   The code `list_2 = list_1` does NOT mean that *list_2* is an alias to *list_1* variable. The variables *list_1* and *list_2* are object references or pointers to objects. Changing list_2 or list_1 to reference to a different object will not affect the other.
2. object manipulation
   The code `list_1[0] = 2` changes the contents of the list object and not the assignment of the *list_1* variable.

The following annotates the code statements with that each line is doing:

```
list_1 = [1]     => list_1 points to list object with value [1]
list_2 = list_1  => list_2 gets a reference to same object pointed to by list_1
list_1 = 2       => list_1 now points to object with value 2
print(list_2)    => list_2 still points to list object so value is still [1]
```

You can print out the identity of the object with the [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) function which uniquely defines the object and is constant for the life of the object.

Here is a table showing the line of code in each step, values of each variable after code is executed, and id() of the variables to print the referenced object.

| step | code | values | id() |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | list_1 = [1] | list_1 == [1] | id(list1) = 2989298572224 |
| 2 | list_2 = list_1 | list_1 == [1] list_2 == [1] | id(list1) = 2989298572224 id(list2) = 2989298572224 Both point to same object |
| 3 | list_1 = 2 | list_1 == 2 list_2 == [1] | id(list1) = 140706891962064 => different object id(list2) = 2989298572224 |

After step 2, both variable *list_1* and *list_2* point to a list object with value [1].
After step 3, *list_1* points a different object (i.e. integer object), but *list_2* is unchanged so printing *list_2* at this point prints [1] not 2.

A related [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-variables/) may help to visualize variable assignment and object references.

Comment: Thanks for your post, but I simply do not understand it. List_1 points to object 2. And list_2 points to list_1, which is pointing to 2, so it should give 2?

Comment: @BertHobe you are wrong - your first example prints `[2]` and the second example prints `2`. In the first example both variables reference the same list all the time. In the second example you are assigning a value `2` to the variable `list_1`  in the 3rd line of your code. From then on the variable `list_1` no longer references any list.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Sorry I am confused now. What do you mean with "and the second example prints 2". When I run my code it gives 1 as output?

Comment: Table above shows the variable assignments after each step to help explain.

Comment: Sorry @BertHobe - you are indeed printing the other variable. But `[ ]` around `1` or `2` are important in the print output. They indicate that the variable is referencing a list. Try printing `list_1` and you will see that the second snippet prints value without brackets.

Comment: @BertHobe - try `print(id(list_1))` and `print(id(list_2))` after each step to see the unique identifier of what the variable points to. This [tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-variables/) might help you to visualize variable assignment and object references.

Comment: @BertHobe "`list_1` points to object `2`. And `list_2` points to `list_1`", no, `list_2` points to the same *object* that `list_1` points to at the time you write `list_2 = list_1`. If you change the object that `list_1` is referencing, `list_2` is still tracing the original, old object.

Comment: @CodeMonkey as a side note integer values `0 <= x <= 256` are instantiated only once per Python interpreter run - `id(2)` will always return the same result for the lifetime of the interpreter, so I don't like "new object` in the last row of your table. Other than that your answer is great. Upvoting.

Comment: @jfaccioni "If you change the object that list_1 is referencing, list_2 is still tracing the original, old object." But in my first example, list_1 points to the object [1]. So does list_2. Then I change to what list_1 is pointing to, so list_2 is also updated. So I changed the object that list_1 is referencing, but list_2 is not tracing the original old object. It is now tracing the new?

Comment: @CodeMonkey Thanks for the hint with the print id, but I still haven't understood it unfortunately :-(

Comment: @BertHobe in your first example you are not changing what `list_1` is referencing - you only insert integer 2 at index 0 of that list.

Comment: @BertHobe "Then I change to what `list_1` is pointing to, so `list_2` is also updated", no, you did not change the object that `list_1` *points to*, you modified the object itself (because a list is a mutable data structure). That very same object now holds different data inside it, which is reflected when you access it through `list_2`.

Comment: Suggest to follow through related tutorials: https://realpython.com/python-variables/ and https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/py/python-var.html. It's important to understand difference btwn variable assignments vs the value of the object (e.g. contents of a list, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Please extend your code a little bit:

```
list_1 = [1]
list_2 = list_1
list_1[0] = 2
print(id(list_2) == id(list_1))
print(list_2, type(list_2))
print(list_2[0], type(list_2[0]))
print(list_1, type(list_1))
print(list_1[0], type(list_1[0]))
```

to see that all the time you are operating on one list.

Now extend the second snippet to see that list_1 no longer references any list in the end:

```
list_1 = [1]
list_2 = list_1
list_1 = 2
print(id(list_2) == id(list_1))
print(list_2, type(list_2))
print(list_2[0], type(list_2[0]))
print(list_1, type(list_1))
print(list_1[0], type(list_1[0]))
```

effectively causing the last line to throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

This is mainly because in Python everything is considered an object therefore when you pass an variable pointing to a list into another variable it accepts not the variable but the object of the variable inside it therefore referencing it. That is why when you changed the list_1 values it modified the object and therefore in turn list_2 having a reference of that object it prints out the modified list.
In second case the first object is inside the second list but you changes the variable pointer to another object but the second list still contains the first objects reference therefore it did not change.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.